# How to remove or get distinct values in C# LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a Database data I have written a join query to join two tables and then select the data based on PhotoContestID, but I want unique values
Below is the join query and its result

```
select *
from PhotoContest.ContestImageLibrary
Left Join 
PhotoContest.ContestCategories On 
PhotoContest.ContestImageLibrary.PhotoContestID = PhotoContest.ContestCategories.PhotoContestID;
```

I want to get unique values based on ImageID FirstorDefault.
I don't want duplicated records, like for eg, ImageID

I have written the below code to get the details but I am getting duplicates. I have tried using `Distinct` at the end but no use.

```
 var voteList = (from i in context.ImageLibrary
                            join p in context.ContestCategories on i.PhotoContestID equals p.PhotoContestID
                            select new VoteLists()
                            {
                                PhotoContestID = i.PhotoContestID,
                                ImageID = i.ImageID,
                                ImageCaption = i.ImageCaption,
                                ImageName = i.ImageName,
                                categoryName = p.categoryName,
                                isImageAccepted = i.isImageAccepted,
                                catID = p.Id,
                                empID = i.empID,
                                votingType = p.votingType
                            }).Where(x => x.PhotoContestID == id).ToList();

            }
```

What shall I write exactly in my backend to get the desired unique result or maybe I can't get unique values based on ImageID.

Thanks

Comment: What about all those other fields (which are not really duplicated, as is just imageID taken by itself). What do you do with those?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @topsail it does not matter about other fields , i just need single value based on imageID, 
Like if you see for PhotoContest 50 , there should be just 4 records based on ImageID , i don't want 8 records to be shown.

Comment: Can you give example data from both tables? Your data doesn't make sense - you have two categoryID fields, with different values. I don't see why PhotoContestID is in either of these tables either. The structure seems very odd.

Comment: If you are using LINQ to database (depending on the specific implementation and version you are using), you would use group by to combine on `ImageID` and then need to make some decision on how to pick from each group (e.g. first, last, combine values, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that multiple categories match each single image.

I would say you need to use a GroupBy with all duplicated fields in the key, and that will force you to specify how to manage the multiple matching categories in the value part.

Comment: Yes , even i was thinking to get details by GroupBy, but how shall i write in C# LINQ query, sorry i am new into this.

Comment: Why do you need to join with the categories table ? Is it only for filtering purposes ?

Comment: Yes i want for filtering purpose , i am trying to get categoryID for each imageID

Comment: Or maybe you should be using    `join p in context.ContestCategories on i.PhotoContestID equals p.PhotoContestID && i.categoryId equals p.Id`

Comment: or simply     `join p in context.ContestCategories on i.categoryId equals p.Id` ?